# Add module definition to existing module

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-6

So, I've developed a great module and integrated all over the installation on multiple pages.
The next day comes the customer and they want another view added to the module. So I build another module definition. Problem is, now I have to install the whole module again and remove all other (a lot right now) module definitions with the exception of the newest.

Is there a way to work around this? I even prefer to do it by programming, code-wise adding a new module definition to the page.

*EDIT:*

For example I've got a page with my module installed. The page will then have the following module definitions:

- `ModuleDefinitionA`
- `ModuleDefinitionB`
- `ModuleDefinitionC`

Now I update my module by adding another module definition and I have to install it on the page again:

- `ModuleDefinitionA` <-- from previous install
- `ModuleDefinitionB` <-- from previous install
- `ModuleDefinitionC` <-- from previous install
- `ModuleDefinitionA` <-- from new install
- `ModuleDefinitionB` <-- from new install
- `ModuleDefinitionC` <-- from new install
- `ModuleDefinitionD` <-- new definition from new install

*How can I add only `ModuleDefinitionD` without adding all the other duplicate module definitions?*

(not a novice at DNN module development)

Comment: Uninstalling module can cause the problem! Since DNN will uninstall all the related module instances from all pages.  

Good approach is to increase version number of the module and upgrade the module. It will not affect existing pages. You can just remove and add module where you want new view.

Comment: @PrashantLakhlani yeah thats what I normally do. I'll edit post and explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you are asking is possible. Remember DNN modules are DotNet code which is compiled code, so any time a new View(ascx control) is added or a change made to the project's code, the module has to be recompiled with Visual Studio(or similar tools), and then reinstalled. Increment the module version number and DNN will notice it's an upgrade and only run sql scripts that match the module version number.

Plus, when you update a module, every running instance of the module is updated, so you don't have to remove and then re-add the module back to the pages.

Comment: To get the newest module definition on that page, I **do** have to at least remove the duplicate module definitions.

Comment: But thank you for your post, it's a confirmation about what I already thought (until someone comes with a solution).